# How to convert CSV file into YAML file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv, yaml

I have a CSV file where it contains URLs, Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDN), Domains, IP addresses and ranges of IP addresses. And I would like to convert it to a YAML file on the following format:

```
entity:    
  name: "company name"   
  network_names:
    url: 
      - 'scheme://host:port/path?query'
      - 'http://www.example.com/software/index.html'
    fqdn:
      - 'mymail.somecollege.edu'
    domain:
      - 'somecollege.edu'


  network_addresses:
    ipv4:
      single_ip: 
        - 111.11.111.1
      range: 
        - 111.11.111.0-111.11.11.255
```

The problem is that everything is mixed up on the CSV file, for example on the first row there is an IP address but on the next line there is a URL or a FQDN.

So I was thinking that I need to check if a row contains an IP address, URL, FQDN or a domain and from there build the YAML file.

But how do I specify the fields for the YAML file? I'm new on Ruby programming and YAML.

Comment: What does your CSV look like?

Comment: Size of the CSV and how many lines? I would write my own parser, put it in a hash and then use *Hash.to_yaml*

Comment: What does your code look like? With what *specific* part do you have a problem? Do you get an error message? Which one? Do you get wrong results? What results do you get and what results do you want? Please, provide a [mcve] for us to look at.

Comment: You don't built a YAML file. You build a data structure in memory that then gets dumped/written into a YAML representation in a file. Write a complete YAML file by hand first, load with ruby, inspect the memory layout and generate that layout from your CSV file and dump.

Comment: I don't have any code yet, I'm trying to straight up my ideas first and wanted some advice of people with more experience on this than me. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 2):

here we use [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) ruby gem to generate dummy data

## from .csv file

```
name,email,title,phone_number
Lawerence Kautzer,hedwig@lockman.name,Manufacturing Director,(548) 162-1670 x8532
Mrs. Walter Renner,man@pacocha.org,Legacy Legal Liaison,779-428-7453 x26055
```

## to .yaml file

```
---
- :name: Lawerence Kautzer
  :email: hedwig@lockman.name
  :title: Manufacturing Director
  :phone_number: "(548) 162-1670 x8532"
- :name: Mrs. Walter Renner
  :email: man@pacocha.org
  :title: Legacy Legal Liaison
  :phone_number: 779-428-7453 x26055
```

## do this

```
require 'csv'
table = CSV.table('file_name.csv')
transformed_into_hash = table.map { |row| row.to_hash }
File.open("file_name.yaml", "w") do |f|
  f.puts transformed_into_hash.to_yaml
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic structure. `CSV.parse` can return an array of rows (which can be seen as hashes). Both arrays and hashes can easily be converted to YAML :

```
require 'yaml'
require 'csv'

csv = "ip,something,domain
x,y,z
a,b,c
m,n,o"

data = []

CSV.parse(csv, headers: true).each do |row|
  hash = row.to_h
  # hash looks like :
  # {"ip"=>"x", " something"=>"y", " domain"=>"z"}
  # Apply desired logic to it
  data << hash
end

puts data.to_yaml
# ---
# - ip: x
#   something: y
#   domain: z
# - ip: a
#   something: b
#   domain: c
# - ip: m
#   something: n
#   domain: o
```